# Customize date display format?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, customization, date-and-time

Is it possible to customize the format in which Android displays the current date?

I'm interested mainly in:

1. the date format at the top on screen when pulling down the notification menu (currently for me, it's "DD/MM/YYYY")
2. The date format at the lock screen (currently for me, it's "Weekday, D Month")

I would like to have all dates displayed in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, `YYYY-MM-DD`. The global date format can be changed from settings, but the only available options are `MM/DD/YYYY`, `DD/MM/YYYY` and `YYYY/MM/DD`, and it seems there's no way to define a completely custom date format or set `-` as a custom field separator. This also doesn't affect the lock screen.

I'm using a rooted Android 2.2 (Froyo) with [Samsung TouchWiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz) 3.0. I'm also insterested in answers that require [CyanogenMod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod) or other custom ROMs.

Comment: Isn't it that for the date in the Notification bar, you can simply change it in the *Settings -> Date and Time -> Date Format*? However, I have no idea about the Lock Screen format change.

Comment: Running CM7 here. (This is Android 2.3 but should apply to 2.2 as well; I'll check on my Replicant phone a little later tonight.) I've set the System date format to ISO 8601. The status bar & lock screen haven't changed.

Comment: @SamSPICA There are only three options available, and no way to customize. Sorry for not being clear enough, I added more details to the question.

Comment: any updates on this? android 10 doesn't even have date format settings anymore... 

Answer (score 3):

The Notification Bar uses the global date format. So, just switch to the desired format from `Settings` ~> `Date and time` ~> `Select Date Format`.

For the lock screen, use a lock screen app. Search the Play Store, you can find many.

Comment: You can only select three different options from the settings, no way to customize. I provided more details to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I assume from the second part of your answer that there is no way to change the built-in lock screen format? (I generally try to avoid installing apps unless I'm sure there's use for them.)

Comment: @Ilari Then, there's no way to do this.. :( sorry!

Comment: On android 6, marshmallow, the same setting works for both.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem. It seems to be in many ROMs that you have to change the language to access other date-time formats. I had to change for instance to German, since none of the options for English supported DD.MM.YYYY format.

Hope this helps. Simply try out languages you would like to use most and see in date time settings, whether they support your desired format.